# Cannot type in password field with draggable="true" in Safari

Tags: html, input, safari, drag-and-drop, draggable

In Safari (8.0.8 on OS X 10.10.5 at least), setting draggable="true" on a password field prevents you from typing in that field.

```html
<input type="password" draggable="true" />
```

I seem to be the first person to encounter this issue, so I thought I'd open a question to document it somewhere. Does anyone know any workarounds to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seem Safari automatically adds `-webkit-user-select:none` when draggable.

You can simply add `input[draggable="true"]{-webkit-user-select:text !important}` to your css and it will work again.